# Python lists counting with len() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem for counting a list elements in python 3.x.

```
inimesed = ['John', 'Jane', 'Joe', 'Joeline', 'Parker', 'Allie']

inimesed.append('Paul')

print(inimesed)

len(inimesed)
```

I can't understand what I do wrong, when I start a program the window doesn't show a number of elements on the list, just empty window with sentence 'Please continue'

Comment: You might need to `print(len(inimesed))`, although I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.  Are you running this in some sort of REPL or from a script?

Comment: It should print list elements at least.

Comment: Just for study example on the book Python Crash Course A:Eric Matthes. Im just a begginer, trying to take study examples.

Comment: print(len(inimesed)), this will worked, but on the book was just a list and method like this: len(listname) and i gave a answer there, but thank you anyway your answer solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your reference book is using python interactive shell, that is why it says that len(item) should show something, but normally it doesnt. That is why using

```
print(len(item))
```

is working just fine

in regular files (not interactive shell) to see something on screen you should always use output methods such as print. the objective of python shell is learning, so it prints everything your code returns.

Answer (score 0):

Well your method won't work on certain compilers

```
l = [1,2,3]
print (len(l))
```

This will surely work.

Comment: do not name your variable as list

Comment: can you name the compilers with which it will work?